# Can I create a CSR from Azure Key Vault?

Tags: pki, csr, azure-keyvault

I want to generate a private key in an HSM in Azure Key Vault, and then create a certificate signing request, CSR, containing the corresponding public key.

Is generating the public key, and subsequently the CSR, even possible in Key Vault today - I don't see any mention of generating a corresponding public key in the docs? (Or maybe I just don't understand the nature of an HSM?)

The fallback is, it seems, to create the keys and CSR elsewhere and import the private key into a Key Vault HSM. This is obviously not as good as a private key never having existed outside of the HSM.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to do this on Windows

1. Using the [Azure Key Vault SDK for .Net](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/src/KeyVault), create a key pair in an HSM in Azure Key Vault

   > ```
   > // Assuming you have a keyVaultClient object using the SDK
   > var keyBundle = keyVaultClient.CreateKeyAsync(keyVaultUri, "myKey01", "RSA-HSM", 2048).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
   > ```
2. Get the Public Key of the created key pair as a CSP blob

   > ```
   > var rsaCryptoProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
   > var rsaParameters = new RSAParameters()
   > {
   >     Modulus = keyBundle.Key.N,
   >     Exponent = keyBundle.Key.E
   > };
   > rsaCryptoProvider.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
   > var cspBlob = rsaCryptoProvider.ExportCspBlob(false);
   > ```
3. The subjectPublicKeyInfo component of a PKCS10 (CSR) contains information about the public key being certified. The subjectPublicKeyInfo is ASN1 encoded [CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377463.aspx), of Windows Cryptography API: Next Generation (CNG).

   This section requires some familiarity on how to use Windows Cryptography API: Next Generation (CNG). CNG is a native API, you will need to use PInvoke (DllImport) to call it from managed code.

   > a. Using NCryptOpenStorageProvider (Link limit on SO, Search MSDN)
   >
   > > ```
   > > [DllImport("ncrypt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
   > > private static extern ErrorCode NCryptOpenStorageProvider(
   > >     [Out] out SafeNCryptProviderHandle phProvider,
   > >     string pszProviderName,
   > >     uint dwFlags);
   > > ```
   >
   > open a CNG key storage provider -
   >
   > > ```
   > > SafeNCryptProviderHandle providerHandle = null;
   > > var result = NCryptOpenStorageProvider(
   > >     out providerHandle,
   > >     null,
   > >     0);
   > > ```
   >
   > b. Using NCryptImportKey (Link limit on SO, Search MSDN)
   >
   > > ```
   > > [DllImport("ncrypt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
   > > private static extern int NCryptImportKey(
   > >     SafeNCryptProviderHandle hProvider,
   > >     IntPtr hImportKey,     // NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE
   > >     string pszBlobType,
   > >     IntPtr pParameterList, // NCryptBufferDesc *
   > >     [Out] out SafeNCryptKeyHandle phKey,
   > >     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pbData,
   > >     int cbData,
   > >     uint dwFlags);
   > > ```
   >
   > import the cspBlob from (2) into the key service provider
   >
   > > ```
   > > SafeNCryptKeyHandle keyHandle;
   > > var result = NCryptImportKey(
   > >     providerHandle,
   > >     IntPtr.Zero,
   > >     "CAPIPUBLICBLOB",
   > >     IntPtr.Zero,
   > >     out keyHandle,
   > >     cspBlob,
   > >     cspBlob.Length,
   > >     0x00000040);
   > > ```
   >
   > c. keyHandle can now be used with CryptExportPublicKeyInfo - (Link limit on SO, Search MSDN) to create the CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO structure for CSR object. Look at example provided in the documentation.
4. Fill in the other fields of the PKCS10 (CSR) and ASN1 encode it.
5. Create a hash of the encoded result of (5) using appopriate hashing algorithm. Sign the hash using the private key of the key pair created in (1)

   > var signature = keyVaultClient.SignAsync(keyBundle.KeyIdentifier.Identifier, "RS256", hash).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
6. Attach the signature to the encoded result of (5) and ANS1 encode it again.

Comment: Hi Rohit, thanks a lot. I will try to digest this later; have to admit I'm not big on Crypto API - previous, current, and next gen. But at least your answer indicates there is a way. To us this is really interesting when building token based authentication, in which the entire trust hinges on safeguarding a token signing key.

Comment: And wouldn't it make sense to build support for CSR generation right into Key Vault? Isn't that a common case when generating a private key?

Comment: Same issue for me. Key Vault lacks the very basic HSM features such as sign a CSR internally (without having to export the precious private key).

Answer (score 3):

You might find it easier to use the Windows CertEnroll COM interfaces: Create *and* initialize an IX509CertificateRequestPkcs10 object(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377505(v=vs.85).aspx), populate its properties, then get its RawDataToBeSigned property and send that to Azure Key Vault to be signed. This is callable from native code, .NET, etc.

An alternative [but more complex] approach is to use the underlying Windows APIs which the COM interfaces are built on. This sample (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382364(v=vs.85).aspx) walks through generating and signing such a PKCS#10. Off the top of my head, you should be able to adapt the sample by replacing the calls to CryptSignAndEncodeCertificate with:

1. A call to CryptEncodeObjectEx to ASN.1 encode the CERT_REQUEST_INFO object into binary; and
2. A call to Key Vault to sign that binary blob.
3. You would then need to construct a CERT_SIGNED_CONTENT_INFO, setting:

   a.  The ToBeSigned member to the encoded binary from #1;

   b.  The SignatureAlgorithm member to the algorithm used to sign with Key Vault; and

   c.  The Signature member to the signature returned from Key Vault.
4. You would then call CryptEncodeObjectEx again to ASN.1 encode the resultant PKCS #10 into binary.

The solution above is valid, but will actually go through what IMO is the more complex approach via .NET interop (replacing the Crypto API v1.0 calls in the sample with Crypto Next Gen calls). I wouldn't begin there unless I had a specific reason.